# Is there a module that can display items in database?

Tags: database

after a few rounds of research, seems like Drupal is the way to go to manage data, but I'm fairly new to this...

I want to build a website that displays entries in the form of a table from a database.

For example,
1. User type in words of interest in the search bar
2. Data will be retrieved and displayed, which they can use for comparison (ie between data 1 and data 2)

One very similar example is like,
http://www.eigenfactor.org/

Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to be asking how to build a whole site based on a vague spec, and also how to replicate functionality of another site.

Comment: No no @rooby, he's looking for something specific and there's only one word to describe it.  On three.  One...Two...Three...`Views`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module to display list of content.

> Views module provide functionality to admin to display list of content
>   in any format without using code.

If you want to implement `autocomplete` functionality with views, then you can use [views autocomplete filters](https://drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters) module.

> Views autocomplete filters module provide functionality to set
>   autocomplete to node title or any fields.